# Functions whose derivatives cycle through the cube roots of unity

Tags: complex-analysis

Does anyone know if there exists three complex-valued functions, $f, g, h$ such that

$f' = e^{\frac{1}{3}i\pi}g$
$g' = e^{\frac{2}{3}i\pi}h$
$h' = f$

and are they unique?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, they can't be unique, since the set of solutions is a vector space.

Comment: $e^{i\pi/3}$ is a primitive sixth root of unity.

Comment: @Qiaochu: That's not quite sufficient; the vector space could consist only of the trivial solution. The solution can't be unique because the set of solutions must be a three-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Thanks everyone... I'm sorry that I phrased my question very badly... as jspecter has pointed out, a confusion between $\pi$ and 2$\pi$ led me to not actually write the cube roots of unity as I meant to... also I meant to put some conditions on the functions at c = 0 to get uniqueness... basically I am trying to find the cube root equivalents of sin and cos, if they exist... however the two answers certainly point me in the right direction... thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general solution $(f,g,h)$ is given by
$$
f(z)=\sum_\omega c_\omega\mathrm{e}^{\omega z},\quad
g(z)=\mathrm{e}^{-i\pi/3}\sum_\omega \omega c_\omega\mathrm{e}^{\omega z},\quad
h(z)=-\sum_\omega\omega^2c_\omega\mathrm{e}^{\omega z},
$$
where the sums are over the three cubic roots $\omega$ of $-1$, that is $\omega\in\{\mathrm{e}^{i\pi/3},-1,\mathrm{e}^{-i\pi/3}\}$, and the three coefficients $c_\omega$ are any complex numbers.

The proof is simple: Start from the observation that if $(f,g,h)$ is a solution then the third derivative of $f$ must be $-f$. Deduce from this observation that $f$ must be of the form above. Then assume $f$ is any function of the form above and is part of a solution $(f,g,h)$, deduce the value of $g$ by the first differential equation, then the value of $h$ by the second differential equation. Finally, check that these $f$ and $h$ solve the third differential equation. They do, hence you are done.

Answer (score 1):

For an example, how about

$f(z) = e^{\zeta_6 z}$ where $\zeta_6$ = $e^{2\pi i/6}.$

As for finding all the solutions,

any $f$ with the properties you desire must satisfy the differential equation $D^3(f) + f = 0.$ Thus, the space of solutions for this equation is 3-dimensional generated and by the functions $e^{-z},e^{\zeta_6 z},e^{\zeta_6^5 z}.$

Comment: That gives $f' = e^{\frac{2}{3}i\pi}g$, $g' = e^{\frac{1}{3}i\pi}h$ and $h' = f$.

Comment: @ Condor. Yes it seems as I misread which roots of unity you wanted. I've changed it.

Comment: Where is $f'(z) = \zeta_6 f(z)$ stipulated?

Comment: Quote: Thus the space of solutions is **at most** 3-dimensional.